# iOS) Where should I copy & paste facebook XML snippet?

Tags: ios, xml, facebook, plist

I'm making Facebook Login, I followed all the steps very well but Configuring my info.plist. My xml code is below:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb12345678</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>

<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>12345678</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>AppName</string>
```

I add this xml to the section of 'dict' at info.plist in my project not my projectTest.
So finally, I finished my .plist xml file

But I got an error

```
error: couldn't parse contents of '/Users/~/Desktop/app/app/myproject/Info.plist': The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
```

How can I solve this?

**UPDATE**

Entire .plist is below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.myproject.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1</string>
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>

/*FACEBOOK XML IS JUST BELOW*/ 
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb12345678</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array> 
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>12345678</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>AppName</string>
/**/

<array>
    <string>armv7</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Can you show all of the Info.plist file?

Comment: make sure that your are not adding those inside any other tag other than <dict> , i.e not between any open tags

Comment: @AbdAl-rhmanTaherBadary I updated i think i add those inside <dict> and not between any open tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the snippet in wrong position:

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key> <<----- this one should go with

/*FACEBOOK XML IS JUST BELOW*/ 
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb12345678</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array> 
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>12345678</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>AppName</string>
/**/

<array>                      << ------------- this one
    <string>armv7</string>
</array>
```

Add fb snippet before 
`<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>`

or after

```
    <array>                      << ------------- this one
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: Wow! thank you for your detail but while I fixed this error, i feel very unkind for facebook tutorial... why does position make an error?

Comment: Maybe you understood something. You can add by **Open As -> Property List** mode (instead of open by **source code***). It's easier.

Comment: The error comes because the `<key>` tag has to have the value go behind. It's `<array>                  
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>` in this case. You broke XML format.